# Docusauras - Get Count of items inside a autogenarated Sidebar Category

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I am new to Docusauras and building a tutorial site. I would like to know if there is a way to get the count of items within a sidebar category. In the example below - Foo is a sidebar category and inside the category, there are two files foo.md and foo-bar.md.

```
foo/
    foo.md
    foo-bar.md
```

The output I am looking for is a count. In the above example, **it's 2**. When a new file is added to the folder foo, the count value should automatically get incremented. Does docusauras by default provide the mechanism the retrieve the category item counts by default?

Comment: did you find solution?